# How to draw a polygon with javafx, with a multidimensional array as parameter

Tags: java, json, multidimensional-array, javafx, polygons

I'm trying to draw maps from a series of coordinates which are multidimensional arrays with javafx Polygons.

It works perfectly with only one simple array:

```
Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 });
```

But not with an array from arrays. The coordinates look for example like this:

http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id=62428&params=0

I've been researching all morning but haven't found a useful solution. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Do you have an issue reading the data set into an array of arrays or did you manage to do this and don't know how to display the polygons?

Comment: both. So, I made a small example with an array from arrays but don't know how to make it work when I put it as parameter for the polygon...

    double[] array1 = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 };
   double[] array2 = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0 };
   double[] array3 = new double[] { 2.0, 2.0 };
   double[] array4 = new double[] { 2.0, 1.0 }; 
   double[] array5 = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 };
  double[][] regionsArray = new double[][] { array1, array2, array3, array4, array5 }; 

How can I use my  regionsArray to draw a polygon?

Comment: @FrankPuffer this works: 
Polygon poly = new Polygon(array6);
this doesn't:
Polygon poly2 = new Polygon(regionsArray);

Comment: That data definetly contains at least 3 Polygons. What is the desired output? Also please post the input given in the question and do not just link it. Also posting the sample data as java object structure instead of just positing a giant JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaFX polygon only supports a single contour, so for multiple contours you need to create an array of polygons and loop over it, for example:

```
ArrayList<Polygon> polygons = new ArrrayList<Polygon>;
...
for (double [] region : regionArray) {
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.getPoints().addAll(region);
    polygons.add(polygon);
 }
```

The tricky part will be handling polygons inside other polygons because these should probably appear as 'holes'. But I think that JavaFX can take care of that if you use the right settings for drawing.